# How to add support for `tags = ["manual"]` through a wrapper?

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I noticed that the "unofficial" `py_proto_library` rule in https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/ doesn't respect `tags = "manual"`. More specifically, the rule does two things: generate Python code, and create a `py_library` target. The tags are correctly forwarded to the `py_library` target, but [ignored by the code generation rule](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/2bed3439bb817fabf165dc24d756c907a887b737/protobuf.bzl#L536-L547). So, there's no way to prevent the code generation from being executed when running a wildcard build like `bazel build //...`.

I thought I could work around this by creating my own macro wrapper:

```py
load("@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf.bzl", real_py_proto_library = "py_proto_library")

def py_proto_library(**kwargs):
  """A py_proto_library that respects the "manual" tag."""
  if "tags" not in kwargs or "manual" not in kwargs["tags"]:
    real_py_proto_library(**kwargs)
```

But this is a little *too* respectful of `tags = ["manual"]`. It simply doesn't generate targets with that tag; there's no way to build them at all!

Is there some other approach that will handle `tags = ["manual"]` correctly, i.e. skip the target in wildcard builds, but build it when individually requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`py_proto_library` is actually a [macro](https://bazel.build/extending/macros), not a rule. Macros have to manually propagate tags, because some should be handled differently (for example, if some internal rules are already `manual`, then adding a second one would be an error).

I would approach it by passing the `tags` value to all the relevant functions, and having them each do something like `maybe_manual = ["manual"] if "manual" in tags else []`. Then the rules they create can use something like `tags = ["something"] + maybe_manual`.

That should be a pretty straightforwards and helpful change. I'm not a protobuf maintainer, but I suspect they would accept a contribution along those lines.